# What's the proper way to return a single database result?

Tags: php, mysql

All I want to do is get the firstname result from this function, but it feels it's too much code to do that based on session id.

```
//query_functions.php

function find_name_by_id($id) {
    global $db;

    $sql = "SELECT firstname FROM admins ";
    $sql .= "WHERE id='" . db_escape($db, $id) . "' ";
    $sql .= "LIMIT 1";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
    confirm_result_set($result);
    $name = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result); // find first
    mysqli_free_result($result);
    return $name; // returns an assoc. array
  }

// admin.php

id = $_SESSION['admin_id'];
$name = find_name_by_id($id);

// what is the shortest way to get this $name result?
```

Comment: You're using a very verbose, low-level database API. It would be even more lines of code if you were doing it safely using prepared statements. Consider using PDO or an even higher-level API like Doctrine or something.

Comment: : "It looks like you're writing your own ORM. Have you considered using one that's already written, tested, and widely supported like [RedBeanPHP](https://redbeanphp.com/), [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/), [Propel](http://propelorm.org/) or
[Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent)?"

Comment: Note: The [object-oriented interface to `mysqli`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php) is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface where missing a single `i` can cause trouble. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is largely an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use manual escaping and string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Accidentally unescaped data is a serious risk. Using bound parameters is less verbose and easier to review to check you’re doing it properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this properly using [prepared statements](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) you actually need more code than that:

```
function find_name_by_id($db, $id) {
    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT firstname FROM admins WHERE id=?");
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    $stmt->free_result();
    return $row[0];
}
```

I'm not sure what `confirm_result_set` is so I left it out.

Let's pretend that `$db` was a PDO object:

```
function find_name_by_id($db, $id) {
    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT firstname FROM admins WHERE id=?");
    $stmt->execute([$id]);
    return $stmt->fetchColumn();
}
```

Much less code involved. And for a higher-level API this will be abstracted to a single line of code.

In reality for all cases you'd want to do some error checking, account for no records being returned, etc. Also you should avoid global variables, they're very poor form. Put your code into a class or just use dependency injection as I've done.

Comment: Can you give more insight on why global variables are poor form?

Comment: Cluttering up global namespace, increase code complexity by not knowing where a variable comes from, potential scope problems when you forget global declarations. Really you should be using a properly namespaced class to contain your functionality.